# jQuery select option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you set the "city" value to the same thing as country value when there is no option for a city?

For example, Benin doesn't have an option to select a city inside of it. At this link http://jsfiddle.net/yPb6N/1/, if you select "Benin", underneath the dropdown it displays `Benin undefined`. How do you make it display `Benin Benin`?

```
<select id="country-select">
    <option value="us">US</option>
    <option value="germany">Germany</option>
     <option>Ireland</option>
    <option>Benin</option>
    <option>Italy</option>
</select>

<select id="us-select" class="sub-menu hide">
    <option value="austin">Austin</option>
</select>

<select id="germany-select" class="sub-menu hide">
    <option value="berlin">Berlin</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<font size="5"><font color="red"><div class="countryvalue" >Value</div></font></font> <br/>
​


function countrySelectChanged() {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();
    var selectedCountry = $('#country-select').val();
    if (selectedCountry) {
        $('#' + selectedCountry + '-select').show();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#country-select').change(countrySelectChanged );
     countrySelectChanged();

    $("#country-select").change(function () {
          var str = $('#country-select').val() + " " + $("#" + $("#country-select option:selected").val()  + "-select option:selected").val();
          $("#country-select option:selected").each(function () {
            });
          $(".countryvalue").text(str);
        })
        .change();
    });
​

.hide {
display: none;            
}​
```

My code is not working

```
    if (($('#country-select').val() != "us") || ($('#country-select').val() != "germany")) {
    $("#" + $("#country-select option:selected").val() + "-select option:selected").val() == $('#country-select').val();
}
```

thanks :-)

Comment: Please clarify your question.  I am having difficulty understanding what your goal is.

Comment: Yes, please clarify your goal.

Comment: $('#country-select').val() will always return a value (if selected)... if an option element does not have a value attribute, the text property is implicitly used for the select value, in other words, the other three options will have the text of the option set for their value if choosen.

Comment: for example,Benin doesnt have city options, If you open up this link http://jsfiddle.net/yPb6N/1/, and select "Benin", the value displays "Benin undefined" how to make the value is "Benin Benin" Thanks for your prompt response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
var str = $('#country-select').val() + " " + $("#" + $("#country-select option:selected").val()  + "-select option:selected").val();
```

Needs to be somthing like:

```
var country = $('#country-select option:selected').val();
var city = $("#" + country  + "-select option:selected").val() || country;
$(".countryvalue").text(country + " " +city);
```

This way, if the name of the city doesn't exist, it will use the name of the country. Also, it doesn't perform multiple selectors for the same element, which is wasteful.

[Here is the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yPb6N/6/)

Comment: Thank you Aesthete, thats more logical and understandable. but this link is not a right one :-)

Comment: @olo - I don't know what was wrong with jsFiddle, I fixed the link - it should work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you want to print only the country name if there is no city associated with this country. If so, I have created this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/tSgVL/1/ .

In fact, you have to test if the list associated with your country exists or not :

```
hasCity = $("#" + $("#country-select option:selected").val() + "-select").length !== 0
```

and then print or not the country.

---

**Edit**

It seems that you want to duplicate the country, so depending of the previous test, you will have :

```
str = $country.val() + " " + (hasCity ? $("#" + country_val  + "-select option:selected").val() : $country.val());
```

Answer (score 1):

basically what @Aesthete said, i just refactored the whole function (took some minutes), maybe you like it (i updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yPb6N/4/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var country
    , city
    , $selected
    , $cs = $('#country-select')
    , $cv = $(".countryvalue");  
  $cs.on('change', function() {
      country = $cs.val() || $cs.text();
      $selected = $cs.find(':selected');
      city = $selected.val() || $selected.text();
      $('.sub-menu').addClass('hide');
      if($selected.val()) { 
        $('#' + $selected.val() + '-select').removeClass('hide');
        city = $('#' + $selected.val() + '-select').val() || country;
      }
      $cv.text(country + ' ' + city);
  });
  $cs.trigger('change');    
});​
```